# Trying to Get Property 'parent_id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to get Categories (containing Products) from the admin panel to the header of the site but it only shows one Category. When I click on it to see its related Products I get an error message.

> Trying to get property 'parent_id' of non-object.

The error is on this line:

```
if($categoryDetails->parent_id==0){
```

**ProductsController**

```php
<?php

public function products($url = null)
{
    $categories = Category::with('products')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();
    $categoryDetails = Category::where(['url' => $url])->first();

    if ($categoryDetails->parent_id == 0) {
        //if url is main category url
        $subCategories = Category::where(['parent_id' => $categoryDetails])->get();
        $cat_ids = "";
        foreach ($subCategories as $subCat) {
            $cat_ids .= $subcat->id . ",";
        }

        $productsAll = Product::whereIn('category_id', array($cat_ids))->get();
    } else {
        //if url is sub category url
        $productsAll = Product::where(['category_id' => $categoryDetails->id])->get();
    }

    return view('products.listing')->with(compact('categories', 'categoryDetails', 'productsAll'));
}
```

**listing.blade.php** (I wrote this to relate it with Categories)

```
{{ $categoryDetails->name }}

<!--the below code is working in index.blade.php and here as well
@foreach($productsALL as $product)
    {{ $product->product_name }}
@endforeach-->
```

Comment: That means there's no category with 'url' equal to $url in you DB

Comment: wouldu prefer to provide any solution

Comment: Do dd($categoryDetails); just after $categoryDetails = Category::where(['url' => $url])->first(); to see if a) you are getting any records returned and b) if the format is as you expected.

Comment: My suggestion is to wrap your if/else statement inside `if($categoryDetails){  }` to make sure the object isn't falsy/null or empty before using it.

Comment: @Petay87 the output is "null"

Comment: Then Category::where(['url' => $url])->first() is returning no results. I would check that $url is what you expect it to be in the same way and then try using php artisan tinker to see if your query works as expected.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  its showing null using dd()

Comment: Category::where(['url' => $url])->first() i add it to see the results related to that category, i mean that i click on any category then it show its related products on another page which is listing.blade.php

Comment: @Petay87 tinker is showing this:  function dd($var, ...$moreVars)
    36|     {
    37|         VarDumper::dump($var);
    38|
    39|         foreach ($moreVars as $v) {
    40|             VarDumper::dump($v);
    41|         }
    42|
    43|         exit(1);
    44|     }

Comment: It would be better to use Tinker to test the query rather than dd(); So just run Category::where(['url' => $url])->first(); in tinker but replace $url with what you expect to get.

Comment: Undefined variable: category in Psy Shell code on line 1

Comment: @Petay87 i was random changes and now previous error has removed and it says: Undefined variable: productsALL at listing.blade.php (its code is mentinod above)

Comment: Make sure $productsAll is populated in the controller

Comment: @Petay87 thnx a lot bro